# Вывести цифры масиива arr1 которые повторяются 3 раз подряд. php

Tags: php

Плиз подскажите как решить данную задачу через цикл for. На словах!
$arr = [ 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4];

Comment: цикл от нуля до `count - 3` напишите и сравнивайте i, i+1, i+2 элементы. если равны, то выводите число. У вас еще каике-то варианты есть, или в этом что-то сложное?

Comment: Прошу вас еще раз написать более Понятнее!!!

Comment: Берете элемент массива. Смотрите равны ли между собой взятый элемент, следующий элемент и следующий за следующим элемент. Если да - делаете что надо, нет - берете следующий элемент и так далее.

Comment: а если изменить цетральную 8 в массиве то весь код разломаеться!

Comment: так как вы предложили я сделал, Спасибо)А есть какие нибудь еще варианты через цикл For?.

Comment: Тут нет никакого кода, потому тут нечему ломаться.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = [6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4];

$results = [];

for($index = 0; $index < count($arr); $index++) {
    if(isset($results[$arr[$index]])) {
        $results[$arr[$index]] += 1;
    } else {
        $results[$arr[$index]] = 1;
    }
}

echo implode(', ', array_keys($results, 3));
```

Comment: И как тут учитывается условие "повторяются подряд"?

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = [6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4];

$results = [];

for($index = 1; $index < count($arr)-1; $index++) {

     if ($arr[$index-1] === $arr[$index] && $arr[$index] === $arr[$index+1])
          $results[] = $arr[$index];
}
```

Извините если что, с телефона пишу))